# Start Python script at startup

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, python, startup

I have a script that I run with

```
python3 /path/script.py
```

I cannot figure out how to make the script run at startup.

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: sorry ! its Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does it require anything such as networking? Does it need to be run as a certain user?

Answer (score 5):

Run it as a service.

Create `/etc/systemd/system/myscript.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /path/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run it with:

```
sudo systemctl start myscript    # Runs the script now
sudo systemctl enable myscript   # Sets the script to run every boot
```

There are lots of other things you can do like make it run as a specific user with `User=`, Set it to run only after networking is available with `After=networking.target`, or lots of other stuff. If it launches a GUI, then you'll probably want to run it as a user-service.

See [`man systemd.unit`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd.unit.5.en.html) and [`man systemd.service`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd.service.5.en.html) for more options.

Comment: In debian based systems, you'd need to create `myscript.service` file in `/lib/systemd/system/` directory. Otherwise, you will get an error `Unit myscript.service not found`

Comment: In debian based systems, `/lib/systemd/system` is reserved for unit files deployed as part of packages.  `/etc/systemd/system` is for local configuration (local units, overrides, and install relationships). `systemd` reads both `/etc/systemd/system` and `/usr/systemd/system`.   On non-debian systems, you may find units in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this based on your needs and conditions such as user privileges and the order of execution whether it should wait for other services to start or not. the easiest ones are :

`crontab` can be used like the following:

```
 #crontab -e
   @reboot python /path/your_script.py &
```

Or you can mention the the command in `/etc/rc.local` this on has detailed explanation [*here*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4123/running-a-python-script-at-startup)

Based on your needs to see logs or other details you can use other options [*here*](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/)